# error in loading native_sample library

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

Following is output in console:-

```
10:51:01 Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Tutorial 3 - Add Native OpenCV
"C:\\ndk\\android-ndk-r8b\\ndk-build.cmd" 
"Compile++ x86  : native_sample <= jni_part.cpp
SharedLibrary  : libnative_sample.so
Install        : libnative_sample.so => libs/x86/libnative_sample.so
10:51:09 Build Finished (took 7s.349ms)
```

i have integrated opencv with android and my project build successfully but when i run my project on emulator the project force stopped and there is an error of

```
cannot load native_sample library
```

here is the code

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                 System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
                 System.loadLibrary("native_sample");

                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            }
```

i have also included manualy this lib.

Comment: Have you inserted the line LOCAL_MODULE:= native_sample in your Android.mk file?

Comment: yes..it is included in Android.mk file.